# How to insert an imported standalone tikzpicture and its caption on the extra margin of the indented paragraph on a specified location

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I have a standalone tikzpicture and I want to put it in the left extra margin (blank space) created by an indented paragraph satisfying all these conditions simultaneously as below:

1. I do not want to define tikzpicture in the main tex file and I want to import it by using `\includestandalone[width=.3\textwidth]{mytikz}`
2. My main tex file has .5 inch left margin dictated by  `\geometry{left=.5in}`
   and an extra 2.25 inch margin dictated by `\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}`;
   I do not want my picture go into the .5 inch margin, my picture must be put 
   only in the 2.25 inch indented margin
3. The location of the figure must be controlled by `\begin{figure}[h!]` I do not 
   want to float its location
4. My figure needs to have caption in the 2.25inch indented margin
5. Also I do not want to break my paragraph to create a gap because of the figure

Here is the standalone tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick](-1,0) circle (1.5);
\fill[blue!50] (2.5,0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);
\draw[ultra thick, ->] (6.5,0) arc (0:220:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is my main tex file:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
 {\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
 \pagestyle{plain}
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
 \section{Introduction}\label{Intro}
 \chapter {Dogs}
 Dogs\\
 Dogs.................
 \section{Cats}
 I put some words before the figure\\
 I put some words before the figure\\
 \begin{figure}[h!]
 \includestandalone[width=.3\textwidth]{mytikz}
  \caption{My TikZ picture}
  \label{fig:tikz:my}
  \end{figure}
  Do not want to break  the words because of the figure. I like to put my 
  figure at the indented margin.\\
  Do not want to break  the words because of the figure. I like to put my 
    figure at the indented margin.
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figure environment **always** takes up the entire column or page.  You need to use either wrapfig or a minipage.  This solution uses a minipage and overlaps the margin using `\llap`.

While `\noindent` isn't strictly needed here, some form of `\leavevmode` is needed before `\llap`.  `\raisebox` also serves two functions, aligning the top of the image with the top of the text at this point, and vertically overlapping the text.

Finally, I replaced `\includestandalone` with `\includegraphics`, since the image file is available.  I also removed the tikz and standalone packages, but added graphicx (normally loaded by tikz) and caption (needed for `\captionof`). I added the `[showframe]` option of geometry to make the margins visible.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in,showframe}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[EL,OR]{\textbf 
 {\thepage}}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
 \pagestyle{plain}
 \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
 \section{Introduction}\label{Intro}
 \chapter {Dogs}
 Dogs\\
 Dogs.................
 \section{Cats}
 I put some words before the figure\\
 I put some words before the figure\\
 \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{% overlaps starting here
 \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test5}% local filename
  \captionof{figure}{My TikZ picture}
  \label{fig:tikz:my}
  \end{minipage}}\hspace{\columnsep}}% add gap inside \llap
  Do not want to break  the words because of the figure. I like to put my 
  figure at the indented margin.\\
  Do not want to break  the words because of the figure. I like to put my 
    figure at the indented margin.
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hello John. Thanks for your support. But this is not what I asked. I want the figure be in the indented margin.

Comment: Even easier.  You dn't need a minipage for the text.

Comment: Hello John. I highly appreciate your kindness+ support+ great and very deep detailed oriented knowledge. Thank you so much!